# I got "ERROR nothing RPROVIDES" during bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake, libcrypto

I tried to run

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

but I got

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'libcrypto' (but /home/yocto/fsl-4-14-98/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-minimal.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
```

In core-image-minimal.bb I have

```
SUMMARY = "A console-only image that fully supports the target device \ hardware."
IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash"
LICENSE = "MIT"
inherit core-image
```

I also got a second error

```
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-minimal' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image-minimal', 'libcrypto']
```

What am I missing? It's my first time using Yocto.
You can find the tutorial I'm using below:

```
- prepare system for Yocto
  $ sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \
     build-essential chrpath socat cpio python python3 python3-pip python3-pexpect \
     xz-utils debianutils iputils-ping
  $ sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev xterm
  $ sudo apt-get install make xsltproc docbook-utils fop dblatex xmlto
  $ sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev

- setting up repo
  $ mkdir ~/bin
  $ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
  $ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

- Add the following line to the .bashrc file to ensure that the ~/bin folder is in your PATH variable.
   export PATH=~/bin:$PATH

- configure git:
  $ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  $ git config --global user.email "Your Email"
  $ git config --list


NEW YOCTO RELEASE WITH KERNEL 4.14.98 AND OPEN SSL 1.1.1J
----
  $ cd /usr/bin
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
  $ sudo apt-get update
  $ sudo apt-get install python3.6
  $ sudo rm python
  $ sudo ln -s python3.6 python

- load iMX recipes
  $ cd
### OLD RELEASE ###  $ mkdir fsl-release-bsp
### OLD RELEASE ###  $ cd fsl-release-bsp
### OLD RELEASE ###  $ repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp -b imx-4.1-krogoth
### OLD RELEASE ###  $ repo sync
  $ mkdir fsl-4-14-98
  $ cd fsl-4-14-98
  $ repo init -u https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/imx-manifest -b imx-linux-sumo -m imx-4.14.98-2.3.3.xml
### IMPORTANT ### $ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
  $ repo sync
  $ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
  $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python

- configure machine
  $ DISTRO=fsl-imx-fb MACHINE=imx6solosabresd source fsl-setup-release.sh -b rsr1296

- create shared directory
  $ mkdir ~/yocto
  $ mkdir ~/yocto/download
  $ mkdir ~/yocto/sstate-cache
  $ gedit conf/local.conf 

    and add this lines:

DL_DIR="/home/multi/yocto/download"
SSTATE_DIR="/home/multi/yocto/sstate-cache"
CONNECTIVITY_CHECK_URIS ?= "https://www.google.com"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "pcsc-lite openssl-bin libcrypto"
PREFERRED_VERSION_openssl = "1.1.1j"
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += "packagegroup-fsl-optee-imx"
BAD_RECOMMENDATIONS += "udev-hwdb"

    comment out this lines

#PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
#PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"

- update Open SSL to 1.1.1J (http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl?h=master)
  $ cd ~/fsl-4-14-98/sources/poky/meta/recipes-connectivity
  $ mv openssl /home/multi/Documents
  $ tar xvzf /home/multi/Documents/openssl_1.1.1j.tar.gz
  $ cd -

- compile full system
  $ bitbake core-image-minimal
```

Everything is fine with no errors in log until `bitbake core-image-minimal`

Comment: share your tutorial

Comment: @amin my tutorial is a .txt my boss gave me. Do you want to read it all?

Comment: Could you provide full steps to reproduce and full logs, including the version of Yocto that was used ? libcrypto is supposed to be provided by "openssl" which is part of "openembedded-core" and thus should be available. Random guesses could be a blacklisted license ("openssl") or incompatible architecture.

Comment: @yadutaf I edited the post with the tutorial step by step. I checked if I have openembedded-core and I don't have it. I have meta-openembedded.

Comment: I added openembedded-core in my layers but bitbake told me: `Layer yocto is not compatible with the core layer which only supports the se series: kirkstone langdale (layer is compatible with sumo)`.